# .NET Runtime Error Event Id 1026

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework-6

I have a WPF application I have created on a Windows 8.1 machine targeting .NET runtime 4.5.1.  It runs fine on the development machine.

I am trying to install it on a Windows 7 machine. It has .Net 4.5.1 installed. When I try to run it on the Windows 7 Machine the login window comes up. When I enter the password, the application verifies the password then it crashes. I have verified that it is connecting to the server to verify the password...so it's not a SQL Connection error.

So it appears that it happens when the main application windows is trying to display. Here is the info that gets recorded in the Application log. Notice the framework version. The app is targeting 4.5.1. So I don't understand why it is showing 4.0.30319.

```
Application: HardwarResources.WPF.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Data.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException
Stack:
  at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
  at HardwareResources.WPF.MainEntry.Main(System.String[])
```

The only other pertinent information is Event ID: 1026.

HELP!

Comment: Event ID 1026 just means that the event log entry was done by the .NET runtime. You get a EntityCommandExecutionException, but it is odd that the stack trace shows at topmost entry Window.ShowDialog(). It smells like you have some databound controls in that dialog which are mapped through the entity framework. And something went wrong with the data mapping. I guess your two best bets are (A) trying to handle this exception in the main method to get more detailed information, and (B) verifying the Win7 setup runs under the same conditions (access to same databases/sources, etc.) as under Win8.

Comment: That was it! I forgot to run some database update scripts on the target database. Thank you!

Comment: Framework Version v4.0.30319 is also expected, as that's the version number of core CLR, which remains the same for .NET 4/4.5/4.5.1

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I copied the .exe file (Debug or Release) to another machine and it would simply not work! Showed up in task manager for a few seconds and would disappear leaving only an ArgumentOutOfRangeException and a Kernelbase.dll error in the application event logs. So I decided to install Visual Studio on the machine where the file would not launch. After copying the project folder to a different file structure than on the original machine and hitting compiling it, I found out that I was trying to cut a string (file path) shorter than it was (due to different file structure). So the problem was in the code itself and NOT in any .dlls or .NET versions.
Hope I have helped!

Comment: Same problem but I cannot not find root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an event handler to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` to trace more detail about the error. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) for reference on catching unhandled exceptions.

I'm thinking it's something to do with cross-threading, thread synchronization context (requiring invoke) or perhaps missing `[STAThread]` attribute on `Main`.

If you're trying to feed data to a dialog, you have to go about it in a thread-safe manner.